# How to calculate the hash (or not hash) value of the directory name in winsxs folder?

Tags: windows, hash, winsxs

**Background:**

1. When installing windows updates, the windows installer will check the version of some .dll files first, which can be found in the winsxs folder

2. The directory name in the winsxs folder is the combination of different attributes of the dll:

> amd64_microsoft-windows-wintrust-dll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23468_none_4e2b9c2fc9f33913

**Question:**

It is clearly that:

**amd64** means the processor architecture

**microsoft-windows-wintrust-dll** means the name of the dll

**6.1.7601.23468** means the version

**none** means the culture (or language)


But I can't figure it out that what's the meaning of "4e2b9c2fc9f33913"? I guess it is a hash value, but I don't know how to calculate it.


I found some related questions on the Internet but all the answers didn't include how to calculate this value. Does any know it?


Thanks.

Comment: See this article: [SXS, hashing and persistence](https://stolenbytes.com/?p=177). It features code decompiled from the relevant DLLs.